# Transfer from Stripe to another Stripe account

Tags: stripe-payments

I implemented Stripe connect which provides token and other useful property of the signee(user). From the tokens provided, is there a way transfer payment from my account to the user Stripe account? This  an option `https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collecting-fees#charges` for me right now because I would like to collect the payments first then transfer it later to the user(recipients).

Comment: Perhaps an option is to create a delayed payment, through a sort of subscription method. Have no experience with it though (yet).

Comment: I have multi vendor websites and my vendors get there sale amount into their stripe account. Now i want to take fees from them for website wallet. They can recharge wallet with cc and charge them . but I NEED TO OPTION to use their stripe balance to pay. LIKE we use paytm,paypal instead CC each time. How we can provide pay with stripe option to vendors so they can pay from their stripe account balance instead CC.

Answer (score 1):

there does seem to be support for this now:
https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-migrate-to-a-new-stripe-account

Answer (score 0):

Right now (September 2014) Stripe does not support Stripe account-to-Stripe account transfers in any way. If you have a US Stripe account, you'd be better off using our transfers API, which would allow you to accept the payments and then transfer them to a third-party bank account when appropriate:

https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers

Cheers,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.

Comment: It looks like Stripe makes this a little easier now  https://stripe.com/docs/connect/migrating I'm looking at my options for my own work.

Comment: @Larry Ullman does Stripe Support this now.?? if not then what is the alternative of this kindly please help me on this .